# ResourceProcessor is not working with PagedResources

Tags: spring-data, spring-hateoas, spring-rest

Hi I'm trying to add some custom links into the Paged resources without success. This issue may be related to [DATAREST-375](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-375) but can someone please verify that I'm doing this right.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/photos")
public class PhotoController implements ResourceProcessor<PagedResources<Resource<FileInfo>>> {

private static final String MEDIA = "media";

@Autowired
private FileSystemService photoService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<PagedResources<Resource<FileInfo>>> getAllPhotos( Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler<FileInfo> asemb ) 
        throws IOException {
    Page<FileInfo> imagesInfo = photoService.getImagesInfo(pageable);
    return new ResponseEntity<>( asemb.toResource(imagesInfo), HttpStatus.OK );
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<GridFsResource> getPhoto( @PathVariable("id") String id ) throws IOException {
    GridFsResource imageByName = photoService.getImageById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>( imageByName, HttpStatus.OK );
}

@Override
public PagedResources<Resource<FileInfo>> process(PagedResources<Resource<FileInfo>> resources) {

    Collection<Resource<FileInfo>> content = resources.getContent();

    for (Resource<FileInfo> resource : content) {
        try {
            resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(PhotoController.class).getPhoto(resource.getContent().get_id().toString())).withRel(MEDIA));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    return resources;
}
```

}

Comment: Is spring-data-rest on the classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried around a little and found a way to to this:

1. Your resource processor should target the element type - so implement
   `implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<FileInfo>>`
2. To integrate with spring data rest your controller should not be an `@RestController` but a `@RepositoryRestController`
3. If you use RepositoryRestController you need to autowire the `PagedResourcesAssembler` instead if passing it as a method argument

That should result in something like this:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/photos")
public class PhotoController implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<FileInfo>> {

private static final String MEDIA = "media";

@Autowired
private FileSystemService photoService;

@Autowired
private PagedResourcesAssembler<FileInfo> asemb;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<PagedResources<Resource<FileInfo>>> getAllPhotos( Pageable pageable ) 
        throws IOException {
    Page<FileInfo> imagesInfo = photoService.getImagesInfo(pageable);
    return new ResponseEntity<>( asemb.toResource(imagesInfo), HttpStatus.OK );
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<GridFsResource> getPhoto( @PathVariable("id") String id ) throws IOException {
    GridFsResource imageByName = photoService.getImageById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>( imageByName, HttpStatus.OK );
}

@Override
public PagedResources<Resource<FileInfo>> process(Resource<FileInfo> resource) {

    resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(PhotoController.class).getPhoto(resource.getContent().get_id().toString())).withRel(MEDIA));

    return resource;
}
```

I tried this in a similar setup as yours and that worked.

This part of the documentation gives a little more details on this:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_repositoryresthandlermapping

Comment: Hi Mathias,
I have tried your solution but still link are not populated.

Comment: Do you have spring data Rest in the classpath or just spring hateoas

Comment: I'm using spring boot and in my pom I have both dependencies: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: Looks like spring-data-rest is not picking up the resource processor for custom controllers - currently I do not know how to solve this issue.

Comment: I researched a little and updated my answer - please have a look at what I came up with.